# Estimate occupation time of Brownian Motion

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $V$ be a simple domain (e.g. a sphere) and $\tau_V= \inf\{t\geq0:B_t\notin V\}$, where $B_t$ is Brownian Motion.
I try to investigate the following term
$$E^x[\int_{0}^{\tau_V} g(B_s) ds],$$
with $x \in V$ in a **stochastical** way. For example, I would like to have a lower and/or upper bound. I know that this can be interpreted as a solution of the Poisson problem but I don't want to use pure Analysis methods. 
Does anybody have an idea for an approach that can be used here or can somebody recommend any literature?

Comment: How is $V$ related to $D$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typing error. Every $D$ should be a $V$. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note - I wrote this answer and then realised that I can't come up with anything more creative than solution of Dirichlet problem, which you don't want. I'm posting this anyway, maybe there's someone who doesn't know this "define integral out of simple function" trick.

Let us define $G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt$ and $F(x) = \int_0^x G(t) dt = \int_0^x (\int_0^t g(s) ds ) dt$. Assume $g(0)=0$ for clarity of notation - we're not losing much of generality, but general cleanness of writing improves. Then $G'(x) = g(x), F'(x) = G(x), F''(x) = g(x)$.

From Ito-Doublin lemma we have, for every twice differentiable function f and any semimartingale $X_t$:
$$f(X_t) = f(0) + \int f'(X_s) dX_s + \frac{1}{2} \int f''(X_s) ds$$

Brownian motion is, obviously, a semimartingale. Thefore:
$$ F(B_t) = F(B_0) + \int G(B_s) dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int g(B_s) ds$$

First integral is called continuous local martingale, second one is finite variation part.

Note that we know that $\limsup B_t = \infty$, so it is going to escape any given interval, sooner or later. Therefore any writing of sort $t \wedge \tau_V \rightarrow \tau_V$ if $t \rightarrow \infty$ is true, if we assume that $B_0 \in V$

From this argument we know that $g(B_{t \wedge B_t})$ is bounded. We will change time $t$ in Ito integral above into $t \wedge \tau_V$. If $g$ is bounded, than $G$ is bounded as well. We know that bounded continuous local martingale is martingale, therefore we can write $$\mathbb{E} \int^{t \wedge \tau_V}_0 G(B_s) dB_s = 0$$.

Taking expectations on both side of Ito expansion and using dominated convergence argument (from boundedness we can do it) we therefore get:
$$\mathbb{E} F(B_{\tau_V}) = F(B_0) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E} \int_0^{\tau_V} g(B_s) ds$$

In dimensions $d$, $d>1$, Ito expansion looks like this:
$$F(B_t) = F(B_0) + \sum_{i = 1}^d \int \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} F(B_s) dB_s^i + \sum_{i,j}^d \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} F(B_s) d [B_i, B_j]$$

Since $[B_i, B_j] = t \delta_{ij}$ last part reduces to diagonal Dirichlet operator.

Left hand-side can be reexpressed as Dirichlet problem, but I presume this is something you don't want.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although you somehow end up in the Dirichlet problem it gives me some useful insights. 
However, this approach works only for one dimension as e.g. the doubble integration only works in this case, right?
Additionally, it should be easily possible to calculate the lef hand side of the last line explicitely. Maybe this gives some more insights. I will try this...

Comment: I have extended Ito integral into multidimensional case - maybe it will be helpful. I did not repeat argument with stopping time, but it works perfectly analogously.

Comment: Also, I have just realised that last chapter of LeGall's book on Stochastic Calculus covers local times of Brownian Motion. I haven't read it, but there's non-zero probability that you will find something useful there.

Comment: oh, pardon, I have misunderstood you remark about multidimensional-case - I'm not sure, I think double integration might work, but will require some heavy notational overhead and might be generally painful. But one dimension gives you nice starting point, nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is helpful. I see what I can get out of this

Comment: did you manage to get something useful?

Comment: Well, I've tried to generalize this approach for more dimensions but as I am always ending up in the Dirichlet problem anyway, I discarded the approach after a while, although it contains some interesting techniques. It turns out that this problem is harder than I thought. After many other approaches I couldn't get something really useful as of today...